# How to execute echo %errorlevel% in java

Tags: java, exit-code, runtime.exec, errorlevel

I want to read the return code of a `cmd` command in Java. For that I used:

```
Runtime.exec("echo %errorlevel%")
```

but instead of echoing the error code it is echoing `%errorlevel%`.

Comment: have you tried escaping %? e.g \%errprlevel\%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what are you using this for. But it seems that you want exit code of the command you executed in you program.
If you have `Process` object (corresponding to your command) available, you can either use `process.waitFor()` or `process.exitValue()` methods to get the exit code of your process.

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for this:

System.getenv("errorlevel");

Thanks,
M

Comment: may be but in my case it is givin "null"...:(

Answer (score 1):

if You are trying to get "errorlevel" environment variable, you can use System.getenv()

```
String errorlevel = System.getenv("errorlevel");
```

But the above method is deprecated and it is advisable to use

```
String errorlevel = System.getProperty("errorlevel");
```

Comment: System.getProperty is also givin null as output.I think this can access the env variable we set in our system.I have checked my variables there is no Env Variable named as Errorlevel..

Answer (score 1):

```
Process process = Runtime.exec(original_command);
int exitCode = process.waitFor();
System.out.println("Command returned " + exitCode);
```